# Why are javax.validation.constraints specified on Java Entity field not being mapped to database schema by Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When the SpringBoot application starts, I'd like Hibernate to automatically create the database schema, which works fine.

But I'm not seeing `javax.validation.constraints` have any effect on generated schema.

I have the following Gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("war")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.11"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.11")

    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0")

    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0")

    implementation("javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final")

    implementation("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.1.Final")
}
```

and the following Java Entity class:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Size(max = 10)
    @NotNull
    public String text;
}
```

Why is it that when I connect to my database I don't see any constraints specified for the `text` field inside `Person`?

Shouldn't there be another 'not null' constraint and also a `length` constraint on the `text` column?

[image: List of database constraints]

`application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Comment: The javax.validation constraints are mainly used to validate data at runtime when you perform operations in your Spring Boot application. For example, when you use a validator or during the data binding process in Spring, these constraints will be checked to ensure data integrity.

To enable DDL generation and display database constraints in the schema, you can set the following property in the application.properties file: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate`

Comment: Because by default they don't have an impact (afaik). You need to set the `hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl` to `true`. In this case `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl=true` to your `application.properties` should enable it. That being said it might only work for some common available annotations and not all. Next to that remove the `javax.validation-api` and `hibernate-validator` dependency and use `spring-boot-starter-validation` instead, to get compatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

To add the constraints you could always define them in the @Column annotation

```
@Column(length = 10, nullable = false)
public String text;
```

Comment: I'd like to prevent having to duplicate any constraints that could be shared between Hibernate and JPA